# Data Wont Return

Tags: sql, oracle

I have added a timestamp statement to the below SQL but it is not adding it to the table.

```
with cx(seq, user_id, mod_date_time, menu_optn_name) as (
    select 1, 'U1', timestamp '2007-05-21 16:00:00', 'O1'  from dual),
 cc(seq, user_id, mod_date_time, menu_optn_name) as (
   select seq, user_id, cast(mod_date_time as date), menu_optn_name from cx)

select
  user_id, MENU_OPTN_NAME, MOD_DATE_TIME,
  case
    when MOD_DATE_TIME > prior MOD_DATE_TIME+(1/96) and user_id = prior user_id then round((MOD_DATE_TIME - prior MOD_DATE_TIME)*1440,2)
    else null
  end as TIME_GAP
from
  (select
     ptt.user_id, MENU_OPTN_NAME, ptt.MOD_DATE_TIME,
     row_number() over (partition by ptt.user_id order by ptt.MOD_DATE_TIME) seq
   from PROD_TRKG_TRAN ptt
     join cd_master cm on
       ptt.cd_master_id = cm.cd_master_id
   Where
     MENU_OPTN_NAME = 'Cycle Cnt {Reserve}' --CHANGE BASED ON WHAT YOUR TRACKING... MENU NAMES AT THE BOTTOM
     and ptt.user_id = 'SCOUNCIL' --CHANGE BASED ON WHO YOU WANT TO TRACK FOR A GAP...
     and cm.cd_master_id =
       (select cd_master_id
        from cd_master
        where
          co = '&CO'
          and div = '&DIV')
     and ptt.create_date_time >=
/*Today*/ trunc(sysdate)
--/*This Week*/              trunc(sysdate-(to_char(sysdate,'D')-1))
     --/*This Month*/            trunc(sysdate)-(to_char(sysdate,'DD')-1)
     --/*Date Range*/            '&FromDate' and ptt.create_date_time-1 < '&ToDate'
     --group by ptt.user_id
)cc
CONNECT BY
  user_id = prior user_id
  and seq = prior seq+1
start with
  seq = 1
```

I have the query to show me anything with a time gap greater then 15 will tell me how long the gap is but I want it to account for the start time of the shift being 4PM so if they start work at 4pm and don't do anything in the system until 4:41PM then there was a 41 min gap. 
not sure what I did wrong... I built the timestamp part separate and then put it into the query possibly its not meant to go with a query and should be on its own.
Thanks for any insight with this issue.

Comment: Please post example data, expected results for that data and actual results you're getting from that data

Comment: as you can see below currently the data start at the first time they do something in the system,
so like
USER_ID MENU_OPTN_NAME MOD_DATE_TIME TIME_GAP
SCOUNCIL Cycle Cnt {Reserve} 06/05/2019 4:29:02 PM 2401.55
SCOUNCIL Cycle Cnt {Reserve} 06/05/2019 4:30:36 PM

but I want line 1 to have the time of 4PM so then line two would have the first systematic thing they did making it a 29 min gap... does that make sense? and sorry not to sure how to format it to look right...

Comment: I can only repeat my request: please post at least 5 rows of sample data, nicely formatted as copyable text, and post examples of what you're getting now and what you want. I don't personally care if these examples outputs are screenshots but do NOT post a screenshot of your sample data. Even better, google for SQL fiddle and use one of the sites that supports oracle (sqlfiddle.com, db-fiddle.uk) to build us a sample we can play with. On  these sites you put a sql script that builds a table, fills it with data and then runs your query. We love this because we can quickly try / solve your prob

Comment: Start row numbering from two, because one is reserved for your parametrizing row. Make union of _shift start data_ and data coming from tables. Then you can apply _connect by query_. [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=799237d2ab74c08eeb3208092e155ef2) is an example for two user_ids, it requires adjustments for other periods than one day. Please use dbfiddle or sqlfiddle for such questions otherwise we have to guess what is in which table. Almost blind.